# Rails Object attribute value is getting modified while accessing it in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a News Model with attributes like email, title, slug, ..etc.I wanted to access the slug attribute of an object inside a method in my visitors_controller.

In the rails console, the value of slug attribute is

```
 2.3.3 :002 > @news = News.order(created_at: :asc).last(1)
```

The result is:

```
    slug: "north-korea-threatens-to-shoot-down-u-s-warplanes"
```

I also checked the slug value in my database

```
   select slug from news where id = xxx;
```

The result is :

```
    north-korea-threatens-to-shoot-down-u-s-warplanes
```

The value of slug is appended with " **. . .** " while accessing it inside of a method in a controller .

```
 class VisitorsController < ApplicationController

  def getSlug
  @news = News.order(created_at: :asc).last(1)

  @news.each do |news| 
  slug = news.slug

 # raise slug.to_yaml
  end
  end
```

When I raised it, the slug value is

```
  --- north-korea-threatens-to-shoot-down-u-s-warplanes ...
```

getSlug.html.erb

```
   <% @news.each do |bubble_gum| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= bubble_gum.title %></td>
  <td><%= bubble_gum.slug %></td>
 </tr>
  <% end %>
```

in the view, the slug value is rendering correct, without (**. . .**) appended to the slug.

How can I get the value of the slug attribute without the appended content( **. . .**) inside of a method in a controller.

Any Help is Highly Appreciated.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's up with the `.to_yaml`? Why do you think you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with the `ActiveRecord` query, or being inside a controller.

The `...` you are seeing is simply caused by converting the string to `YAML`:

```
"north-korea-threatens-to-shoot-down-u-s-warplanes".to_yaml
  # => "--- north-korea-threatens-to-shoot-down-u-s-warplanes\n...\n"
```

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Syntax):

> Three periods (...) optionally end a document within a stream.

In the controller, you are converting the string to YAML (`raise slug.to_yaml`), and in the view you are just displaying the string directly (`<%= bubble_gum.slug %>`). That's why you are seeing a difference.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my mistake.